# Codeigniter form validation error_array() empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I'm using the Codeigniter (v3) form validation library, without the form helper (using ajax).

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $data["errors"] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
}
```

When no name is given, $data["errors"] is created. But the array is empty.
Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Check what `validation_errors()` returns.

Comment: An empty array. But updating Codeigniter solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be resolved in the latest version of Codeigniter, released today.
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html?highlight=4312

Comment: this url returning 404 - File Not Found